# Distinct top 10 from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, distinct

I have these two tables in SQLite

```
CREATE TABLE "freq" (
    `id`    INTEGER,
    `translation_id`    INTEGER,
    `freq`  INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `year`  INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`translation_id`) REFERENCES `translation`(`id`) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)

CREATE TABLE translation (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  w_id       INTEGER,
  word       TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  located_in TEXT,
  UNIQUE (word, language)
    ON CONFLICT ABORT
)
```

Based on the values from these tables I want to create a third one which contains the top 10 words for every `translation.located_in` for every `freq.year`. This could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE top_ten_words_by_country (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  located_in TEXT,
  year       INTEGER,
  `translation_id`  INTEGER,
  freq       INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(`translation_id`) REFERENCES `translation`(`id`) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
```

Thats what I tried (for one country and one year) so far:

```
SELECT *  FROM freq f, translation t
WHERE t.located_in = 'Germany' ORDER BY f.freq DESC
```

which has these problems:

- it doesn't add up multiple words from `translation` which have the same `w_id` (which means they are a translation from each other)
- it only works for one year and one country
- it takes veeeeery long (I know joins are expensive, so its not that important to speed this up)
- it contains duplicate `translation.word`

So can anyone provide me a way to do what I want?

The speed is the least important thing here for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you have a cartesian product(there's no relation between your tables).
Besides, you have to use 'group by' clause.
And you can create a view instead a table.
Change your query to:

```
    SELECT sum(f.freq) total_freq
     , t.w_id
     , t.located_in
     , f.year
  FROM freq f
     , translation t
 WHERE f.translation_id = t.id 
 group by t.w_id
        , t.located_in
        , f.year
 ORDER BY total_freq DESC
```